# advice for trainig my AI to generate random names

Tags: python, dataset, artificial-intelligence, generator

I am very new to python but I have this idea in mind. I'd like to create an AI fantasy name generator. I've got a simple one, generating random strings of 3-11 letters, and my idea is: I get a word and decide if it's acceptable (Bggtrkl isn't, while Koerth might be), and in this process I build a dataset on which I'd base the machine learning. My question is - is it possible? If so - where do I begin? What to learn? I am open to any suggestion / advice.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to train AI to create familiar sounding, randomly generated names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081896/how-to-train-ai-to-create-familiar-sounding-randomly-generated-names)

Comment: You asked this questions three days ago -- please edit/update that question before asking the same again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible - the key is to decide the criteria of what is acceptable input. So a first step is to make some rules about what a name is. Everything has to has some kind of boundary or limit which as the coder you'd have to determine because really any combination of letters/numbers/symbols at all could make an acceptable name to someone. This is why in machine learning people are employed to get data from all over to find a pattern to start with.

Then in python these rules translate into the conditions you need to process the input.

(...added...)
There is also the aspect that a name can be recognised according to the context it is in, eg could recognise a word is a name if it only occurs if referring to a person. Once that pattern is determined then the person could be another object such as an organisation or item. Then it is about the patterns in language grammar.  At the start I would focus on that aspect of program design and practice coding how to process the input to fit the original pattern with all the basic data structures available. Then research `machine learning`, `AI`, `NLP` - natural language processing to see how to extend my basic code. So to begin - design first.

Comment: So would I have to write the rules (for example consonant - vowel - consonant - consonant etc, certain combinations of acceptable letters) or can an AI be trained to do so? I'd be choosing the right words personally. If so - how do I begin? Which module to learn? What to focus on?

Comment: have added to answer - that is it for me because this is theory and I personally haven't looked further into this field.

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
import random
print ("Welcome to this random name generator")
stop = 0
while True:
  while True:
    question = input("Are you male or female?\n")
    if question == "male":
         names = ["Dimah","John","Zack","Max","Mattihas","Roy","Don","Liam","William","Noah","Oliver","Elijah","James","Benjamin"]
         break
    if question == "female":
         names = ["Delia","Laura","Layla","Elizabeth","Olivia","Emma","Ava","Joann"]
         break
    print("Please enter a valid answer")
  lastnames = ["Hoosenator","Maloroda","Yu","Smith","Jones","Williams","Brown","Davis","Miller","Wilson","Chan"]
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Your name is " + random.choice(names) + " " + random.choice(lastnames))
while True:
  again = input("Would you like to generate again?\n")
  if again == "yes":
    break
  if again == "no":
    stop = 1
    break
  print("Please enter a valid answer")
if stop == 1:
  print("Thank you for using this random name generator, I hope you are satisfied with it. See you next time!")
  break
```

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better